# An elementary question on Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

We consider the Markov chain $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n\geq0}$
  on $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ 
  with transition matrix

$P=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2
\end{array}\right)$

Set $\tau:=\textrm{inf}\left\{ n\geq1\left|X_{n}=1\right.\right\} $
 . Compute $\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=n\right]$
  and $\mathbb{E}_{5}\left(\tau\right)$
 .

**EDIT:** We have $\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=1\right]=\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[X_{1}=1\right]=1/2$ so by induction we get $\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=n\right]=\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[X_{n}=1,X_i \neq1 \forall i=1,...,n-1\right]=(1/2)^n$. But how to compute $\mathbb{E}_{5}\left(\tau\right)$?

I'm a freshmen of this subject. Help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have never seen a subscript on a probability or expectation like that. What does the "5" subsript mean? Do you mean to simply compute $Pr[\tau=n | X_0=5]$ and $E[\tau|X_0=5]$?

Comment: $Pr_x$ is the probability starting from $x$

Comment: Well, in that case, I notice that from state 5 you can go only to state 5 or to state 1.  (So the other transition probabilities do not matter). So, can you solve it now?  Perhaps you can show some of your work. You do not really need Markov chain theory for this. The random variable $\tau$ has a "name."

Comment: $\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=n\right]$$=1/2$. But how to find $\mathbb{E}_{5}\left(\tau\right)$?

Comment: This cannot be.  Since $1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Pr[\tau=n]$, so if $Pr[\tau=n]=1/2$ for all $n$, we get $1=\infty$.

Comment: As a start, you might try computing $Pr[\tau=1]$, $Pr[\tau=2]$, and so on.

Comment: Could you give me more hints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28852/discussion-between-michael-and-user110834).

Comment: @Michael The notation $P_x$ for $P(\ \mid X_0=x)$ is banal.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=1\right]=\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[X_{1}=1\right]=1/2$$

$$\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=n\right]=\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[X_{n}=1,X_{i}\neq1\forall i=1,...,n-1\right]=(1/2)^{n}$$

Since $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n}=\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}$$
  we get that

$$\mathbb{E}_{5}\left(\tau\right)={\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}i}\mathbb{P}_{5}\left[\tau=i\right]={\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}i}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{i}=\dfrac{1/2}{\left(1-1/2\right)^{2}}=2$$

Comment: Thank you for your help @Michael

Comment: You are welcome.  The random variable $\tau$ turns out to be a "geometric random variable" with success probability $\theta=1/2$ (and so its mean is indeed $1/\theta = 2$).